# How to display the checkbox on the jquery dialog title bar?

Tags: jquery, checkbox, jquery-dialog

Code:

In Jquery dialog,

```
$('#status-dialog')
                .dialog({
                    hide: 'fade',
                    autoOpen: false,
                    resizable: true,
                    title: 'Status',
                    modal: false
                });
```

Index.cshtml

```
<div class ="cb-status">
    <input id="accept-cb-name" type="checkbox"/>
    By Name<br /><br />
</div>
```

How to display the checkbox on the jquery dialog **title("Status")** bar?

Comment: I don't think there is buitin function for this. The best way to create it is to edit the DOM using inspector or firebug (add the input) and then use jquery code to append input to the right place.

Comment: Can you post a sample example of how to accompolish this task, Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check here DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/yeyene/GnpQ8/7/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#dialog-model").dialog({
        create: function (event, ui) {
            $(".ui-dialog-title").html('<input id="accept-cb-name" type="checkbox"/> By Name');
        },
        width: 250,
        height: 150,       
        modal: true,
        resizable: false
    });
    // checkbox event
    $(document).on('click','.ui-dialog-title input', function(){
        alert('Bang !!');
    });
});
```

Comment: How to write click event for the checkbox here?

Comment: One doubt, that is if there are `two checkboxes` and how to check `(using class or anything)` whether `particular checkbox` has been `checked` inside the click event

Comment: check this demo, click red check button and see...http://jsfiddle.net/yeyene/GnpQ8/8/

Comment: first check one or both checkboxes, then click the button and see the checked checkbox value.